# Entity Framework not working correctly with DateTime column when converted to compatibilty 130

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, datetime, entity-framework-6, datetime2

The below code was working with SQL Server Compatibility Level 100.  However updating to 130, starting making the code below fail.  I believe it has to do with the datetime and precision.  The item isnt deleted anymore. Any clue why and is there a work around. We want to use some new functions in the 130 level.

```
_gameJobsRepository.Delete(q => q.GameId == gameJob.GameId && q.DateCreated <= gameJob.DateCreated);
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and data types of the fields?

Comment: Its just a regular .NET datetime, and the column in the database is a datetime datatype.

Comment: And the `gameJob.DateCreated` is also a `DateTime`? Or is it possibly a `string`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/578) with EF6 and SQL Server 2016+ in compat level 130+.  SQL Server introduced a [breaking change](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4010261/sql-server-and-azure-sql-database-improvements-in-handling-data-types), and it broke EF6.

The workarounds are

- Stay on compat level 120
- Change all your `datetime` columns to `datetime2`
- Keep all your `datetime` columns and use a command interceptor to change the parameter types (see the github issue)
- Migrate to EF Core

Also this *might* get resolved in EF 6.3, but there's been no commitment, as it looks like a bit of work to fix without introducting breaking changes.

Comment: When you say might, what do you know? Your name has Microsoft in it.  Would changing everything to datetime2 have any negative impacts?

Comment: What do I know: I'm not on the team, and know only what I read on GitHub and guess from looking at the source code.  As for datetime2, it should "just work" unless you have very old drivers that need to access this database.

Comment: +1 for the link to the github issue.  There is a IDbCommandInterceptor workaround provided there that fixed my issue.  DOesn't work in all cases, but might save people some headache until you can migrate to EF Core.