# Entity Framework: how to properly add entities with composite primary key?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, entity-framework

In EF 6 with a database-first approach, is there something special that needs to be done to add an entity to its set collection when the entity definition contains a primary key made up from two columns?

I've been running into the following error:

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: 'Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.'

Here is the high level setup:

1. DB First
2. Primary key from two columns defined on the table:

   - RecordId: int identity
   - Created: datetime
3. Both columns set to be entity keys via the EDMX

And some example code:

```
Dim ctx = New TestEntities
Dim newTestRecord = New TestTable
newTestRecord.Created = Now
newTestRecord.DataPoint = "this is a test"
ctx.TestTables.Add(newTestRecord)
ctx.SaveChanges()
```

The exception is thrown when we try to call `ctx.SaveChanges`.

I've observed and tried the following:

1. I changed things so that `RecordId` is the only PK, refreshed/updated the EDMX settings and the insert works.
2. Via step 1, I discovered that the original code is definitely interacting with the database because that identity column `RecordId` is incrementing even when the original code throws.  You can also set `Created` to a value which is out of bounds for the SQL `datetime` and you will get an error.
3. I changed things so that `Created` is the only PK, refreshed/updated the EDMX settings and the insert works.

Which gets us back to the question in point: is there something special that you need to do when adding entities that contain a composite primary key?  Is this approach even a doable thing, having a composite primary key where one part is set in code and the other part is set via SQL Server's internal handling of the identity (and so EF won't even know about which value SQL assigns until it gets the response)?

Addendum/background: we're trying to use composite primary keys because we're partitioning the underlying table and need the `Created` field to be part of the clustered index for use by the partitioning function/scheme.

Comment: have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19792295/mapping-composite-keys-using-ef-code-first

Comment: What versions of SQL Server, and EF, and what is the database compatibility level? There's a known issue that can cause System.TateTime to fail to match DATETIME when you think it should.  You can read about here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55853699/entity-framework-not-working-correctly-with-datetime-column-when-converted-to-co#:~:text=This%20is%20a%20known%20issue%20with%20EF6%20and,change%20the%20parameter%20types%20%28see%20the%20github%20issue%29

Comment: Thanks David, unfortunately can't drop the compatibility level to 120.

Answer (score 0):

how can you have an identity column and another primary key? This could be your problem, EF assumes identity = unique primary key, nothing else matters. I imagine them that the code is creating a primary key on RecordID and a unique key on Created.

Setting a composite key in EF "code first" requires you to use the `modelBuilder.Entity<TestTable>().HasKey(k => new {k.RecordID, k.Created} )` fluent declaration in your DBContext, so I would look at the generated code to see where it references your table and see what it is generating.

also: using a date for a partitioning system seems wierd, as the identity functions as a form of date (ie the bigger the ID, the newer it is). So if you replaced it with a sequence, then you could keep the unique incrementing ID and also add whatever date component you need into a single composite key insert.

Comment: Is the model builder/fluent API approach compatible with DB first?

Comment: no, but I meant go and see what its doing. That's what it'll look like if its got it right.

Comment: Ok interesting, I don't know if the DB first approach actually use those APIs.  All of the relationships/definitions of objects are contained in the XML inside/behind the EDMX.  Is there somewhere else I might look?

Comment: I'm not sure of EF6, but modern versions dropped that tooling and [generate the same code you would in a code-first approach instead](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/walkthroughs/existing-database)